# Not able to access process.env.PORT from Heroku after deploying Vue2 + webpack project, any other way I can access the PORT from heroku?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, heroku, webpack, environment-variables

I have different port showing up in client(Vue2) and server(Nodejs), I created vue project with command `vue init webpack <project_name>`. I have tried all the solutions online but still I'm not able to figure out how do I access the process.env.PORT value in vue.

```
NODE_ENV=development
PORT=8000

MONGO_URI=mongodb+srv:\\\mongoURI\\
```

I have no idea what's happening in webpack config, but here's the plugin for env variables in `webpack.prod.conf.js`:

```
plugins: [
    // http://vuejs.github.io/vue-loader/en/workflow/production.html
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': require('../config/prod.env')
    }),

...
]
```

this is my `prod.env.js` where I'm able to access process.env.PORT(8000) from the file `.env` which is at the root of the project

```
'use strict'
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config({ path: './.env' });

module.exports = {
  NODE_ENV: '"production"',
  PORT: process.env.PORT
}
```

And I'm using this PORT from `prod.env.js` in my Vue axios instance, api.js:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default() => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
    console.log("In development, port: ", process.env.PORT);
    return axios.create({
      baseURL: 'http://localhost:' + process.env.PORT + '/api/',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.token}`
      }
    });
  } else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    console.log("In production, api port is: ", process.env.PORT);
    return axios.create({
      baseURL: '' + process.env.PORT + '/api/',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.token}`
      }
    });
  }
};
```

Everthing seems normal in the server side but still you can have a look at my `app.js`:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const routes = require('./server/routes/index');
const connectDB = require('./server/config/db');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');

// load env vars
dotenv.config({ path: './.env' });

// Connect to database
connectDB();

var PORT = process.env.PORT;

// Morgan is an api logger, prints all the api calls in console
app.use(morgan('combined'));

// Body Parse
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Enable cors
app.use(cors());

// Routes
app.use('/api', routes);


// Handle Production
app.use(serveStatic(__dirname + "/client/dist"));

app.listen(PORT, process.env.IP, () => console.log(`Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${PORT}`));
```

I don't see any problem in the implementation, but I think Heroku doesn't change the PORT value in `.env` file when building the vue project so vue end up taking 8000 as port value while node js gets new port value when `npm start` is started
 [This is the screenshot after deploy, as you can see we get new port as usual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbcUW.jpg) but

[you can see here in client I still have 8000 which I defined in .env file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2b2u.jpg)

Is there any other way I can access process.env.PORT, so that after deploying it gets a new port from Heroku???